# If the entries in the model are made on the same date then the fields of this model must be summed up

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a model

```
class paidparking(models.Model):
    adress = models.ForeignKey(Parking, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Адрес парковки')
    carnumber = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Номер автомобиля')
    amountoftime = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество времени')
    price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Цена')
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='Номер телефона')
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Электронный адрес',null=True,blank=True )
    datetimepaidparking = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата и время оплаты')
    expirationdate = models.DateField(null=True,verbose_name='Дата начала срока действия')
    expirationtime = models.TimeField(null=True,verbose_name='Время начала срока действия')
    enddateandtime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True,verbose_name='Окончание срока действия')
```

There is a function

```
startdate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['startdate'], '%d.%m.%Y')
enddate = datetime.strptime(request.POST['enddate'], '%d.%m.%Y')
paymentparking = paidparking.objects.filter(expirationdate__range=(startdate, enddate)).values('expirationdate',
                                                                                               'price')
```

In JS, I get this data and draw graphs

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "date",
        data: {
            'startdate': finalDateStrStart, 'enddate': finalDateStrEnd,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
             if (data.result) {
                    var expirationdates = [];
                    var prices = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
                        expirationdates.push(data.result[i].expirationdate);
                        prices.push(data.result[i].price);
                    }
if(window.chart instanceof Chart)
{
    window.chart.destroy();
}
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("line").getContext("2d");
                    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: {
                             labels: expirationdates,
                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'Оплата парковочных пространств',
                                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                borderColor: 'rgb(144,204,244)',
                                data: prices,
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                        }
                    });
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("bar").getContext("2d");
                    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                             labels: expirationdates,
                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'Оплата парковочных пространств',
                                backgroundColor: 'rgb(144,204,244)',
                                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                data: prices,
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                        }
                    });
                }
        }
    });
return JsonResponse({'result': list(paymentparking)})
```

As a result, I get:

[image]

I need to make a query that would sum the values from the `price` field for the same date in the `expirationdate` field

Right now my query outputs all records if the `expirationdate` field falls within the date range between startdate and enddate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the trick with `values` and `annotate` as described very well [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html):

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

qs = paidparking.objects.values('expirationdate').annotate(Sum('price'))

# if you want to order by date:

qs = qs.order_by('expirationdate')
```

This will output a queryset a list of dictionnaries containing `expirationdate` and `price__sum` as keys.

**Edit:**

For your question in the comment, just add the filter at the beginning of the query:

```py
paidparking.objects.filter(expirationdate__range=(startdate, enddate)).values('expirationdate').annotate(Sum('price'))
```

Comment: How do I get the price now? <QuerySet [{'expirationdate': datetime.date(2021, 4, 30), 'price__sum': 450.0}, {'expirationdate': datetime.date(2021, 5, 2), 'price__sum': 450.0}, {'expirationdate': datetime.date(2021, 5, 5), 'price__sum': 1800.0}]> I used to get it via data.result[i]. price

Comment: I need to sort by date and sum price at the same time. In your example, the sum occurs, but the sorting by date does not occur. How can it be done?

Comment: Your example is sorting, and I need to check whether expirationdate is in the range of startdate and enddate

Comment: You need to use range. https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#range

Comment: I use the range in the request paymentparking = paidparking.objects. filter(expirationdate__range=(startdate, enddate)).values('expirationdate',
 'price').How do I combine these two queries?

Comment: Thank you, everything works. Only how do I now take price__sum in JS:<QuerySet [{'expirationdate': datetime.date(2021, 4, 30), 'price__sum': 450.0}, {'expirationdate': datetime.date(2021, 5, 2), 'price__sum': 450.0}, {'expirationdate': datetime.date(2021, 5, 5), 'price__sum': 1800.0}]>. I used to take it via data. result[i]. price

Comment: It looks like you're using Jquery and i am not so familiar with it. But you can just look up Stack Overflow for how to read Json from a response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use annotate in django orm to get the output for the same.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

PaidParking.objects.values('expirationdate', 'price') \
  .annotate(parking_price=Sum('price')) \
  .order_by('-expirationdate')
```

I suppose this answer is suffice for the asked query.
Reference: [For Basic understanding of the query how it works follow this link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html)

Comment: Your example is sorting, and I need to check whether expirationdate is in the range of startdate and enddate

Comment: For this functionality you can use the filter command, which is already shared by @Guillaume